# Permission Denied trying to write in cache directory

Tags: android, permissions

Trying to download file in cache directory like `context.getExternalCacheDir()` or `context.getCacheDir()` on some devices i'm getting a `Permission Denied` error;

Referring to this guys (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xVh-7ywKpE&t=1580s) i don't need to request permission to access cache directory of my application

Error message I've got from Huawei 4x:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/3C11-1816/Android/data/{my app package}/cache/194751d974025fd4109902d9600b6a09.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How can i solve that problem?

Here is my directory provider where i download files

```
public File provide() {
       File external = mContext.getExternalCacheDir();
       File cacheDir = external != null ? external : mContext.getCacheDir();
       if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
       }
       return cacheDir;
}
```

Comment: `/storage/3C11-1816/....` That is the SD card. Pretty different from getCacheDir(). And that it would be returned by getExternalCacheDir() is strange. But then according to the documents your app should be able to write there if the directory exists. Did you check?

Comment: Yes it's strange, only several users of our app have such error

Comment: Did you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes, have both write and read

Comment: You should also have added if you asked for permission at runtime if you understand the problem.

Comment: `that it would be returned by getExternalCacheDir() is strange.` No. I was wrong. It can return two items. Then the second one is the card.

Comment: `Yes it's strange, only several users of our app have such error –` Ok. But does the directory exist? You did not answer my question.

Comment: Added code to the post; I always check if directory exist, and create if needed